# iOS UISearchBar - keep cancel button active at all times

Tags: ios, full-text-search, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller, algolia

To preface I'm using Algolia for a searchBar widget.  My screen does not have a navigation bar and I am using the cancel button to dismiss the view.  This works if the search bar isEnabled.  But the cancel button is not enabled after the search button is clicked.

```
// MARK: - SearchBarDelegateProtocol
public func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

public func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    searchViewModel.search(query: searchText)
}

public func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchViewModel.search(query: searchBar.text)
    self.collectionViewHeightConstraint.constant = 0
}

public func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
   self.collectionViewHeightConstraint.constant = 175
}

public func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).isEnabled = true
}
```